# which font is used in vscode on kde neon linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, fonts, kde-plasma

I have checked
'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'
but none of them is used.

kde neon
[image]

I like the separation of the underscore.

kde neon
[image]
[image]

Neither in kubuntu 21.04, vscode use the same font.
[image]

the 2 font , monospace and droid-sans-fallback don't agree.
[image]

Comment: I think it is Hack font https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/

Answer (score 0):

There is no Droid Sans Mono, so it falls back to monospace, which points to Noto Sans Mono on default KDE installs